# Auto-generated bundle files not created in a Vaadin Project with I18N4Vaadin

Tags: java, maven, internationalization, vaadin7

I am trying to start a new Vaadin project with I18N4Vaadin for internationalization by following this tutorial: https://github.com/peholmst/I18N4Vaadin/wiki/Using-I18N4Vaadin-with-CDI but I couldn't generate the auto-generated files (.java and .properties bundle files).

Besides that, I have added the Abundleperclass tag to the pom.xml.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Abundleperclass>true</Abundleperclass>
                </compilerArguments>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

These auto-generated files should be created just after the deploying, right?

Is there something missing?

Thank you in advance!